# Как сделать КулДаун этому коду?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется код который скачивает что-либо с сайта с помощь URL, мне нужно чтоб он делал это кулдауном в минуту т.е скачивал файл каждую минуту

```
import wget

print('Начинается загрузка файла...')

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B4xdz5zH4Ug.png/'  
wget.download(url, 'C:/Users/Programmer/Downloads')
```

Comment: 1) Засунуть в цикл 2) Добавить time.sleep(60)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `sleep` из модуля `time`, предварительно обернув код в цикл `while`.

***Пример:***

```py
import wget
from time import sleep


def main():
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B4xdz5zH4Ug.png/'
    print('Начинается загрузка файла...')

    while True:
        wget.download(url, 'C:/Users/Programmer/Downloads')
        sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```